# YellowPages Scraping

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to parse Yellow Pages website . http://www.yellowpages.com.au/ rejects HTTP request sent through Jsoup.

```
public class ReadURL {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        parseURL("http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=butchers&locationClue=&lat=&lon=");

    } 
    public static void parseURL (String url) throws IOException {
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
             System.out.println(doc.toString());

}

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Request Rejected</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.
  <br />
  <br />Your support ID is: 5406139567541308211
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just gave it a try, added user agent and it worked:

```
public static void parseURL(String url) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0")
            .get();
    System.out.println(doc.toString());
}
```